# Identify YouTube trailer for Sci-Fi Show

Tags: spaceship, space, story-identification

The plot involved a woman waking up alone on a spaceship in uncharted space. The spaceship has an A.I. which tells the woman that she is the only one on board. When she finds a man asleep she wants to know why the ship lied to her.

That's all I can remember from the trailer.

Comment: When did you see this video?  What country/language?  Any additional details or context you can add would help narrow this down.  Just click 'edit' under your question to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The show is called [Continuum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2309131/?ref_=sr_3). I found it on YouTube.

> A beautiful young woman awakens aboard an adrift space ship with no
>   memory of who she is or how she got there and at the mercy of the
>   ship's mysterious computer.

There is an american show of the same name hopefully u won't get confused

Comment: You should give more details about the show, and a link.

Comment: I think Ean's referring to [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2309131/?ref_=sr_3).

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall all the details about the show, but one possibility is the web series "Ark" with Renee O'Connor. The show starts off with her waking up in something akin to a grave.

Answer (score 0):

> I think Ean's referring to this.

From the question the first thing that popped into my head was the amateurish web series that have 2 saesons as far as i know.

[Continuum](http://www.youtube.com/user/ContinuumTheSeries)

NOT to be confused with the Canadian Sci-Fi series [Continuum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1954347/?ref_=sr_1)!! This one is kinda interesting. Love the timetravel and flash forwards.